# Can someone explain working of this js code with reference to 'this' keyword?

Tags: javascript

**JS code is:**

```
this.sound1 ="global";

function cat(){
    this.sound = 'meawo!!!!';
    this.sound1 = 'meawooooo!!!!';

    meawo1 = function(){
        console.log(this.sound1);
        console.log(this);
    };

    function meawo2(){
        console.log(this.sound1);
        console.log(this);
    };

    this.meawo = function(){
        console.log(this.sound);
        console.log(this);
        meawo1();
        meawo2();
    };

};

var c = new cat();
c.meawo();
```

**Output is:**
[image]

Question: How come `this` inside of `meawo1`(function expression) & `meawo2`(function expression declaration) is referring to "global" and not to object `c`? Why is that?

Comment: Hoisting, perhaps. http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/

Comment: @E I think, it's not. Cause if it would have been hoisted to the scope of `this.sound1='global'` then function call to meawo2() should also work in the global scope which does not.

Comment: Is `var c` inside a function? Or is it in global scope?

Comment: @MarkC. `c` is in global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember a simple tip while wanting to know to which object does `this` refer to.

```
obj.method();
```

In the above, `method`'s is called on `obj`, and hence the `this` in `method` will be what it's called on, i.e `obj = this`.

In your case, though `meowo` is called on `c`, `meowo1` and `meowo2` aren't *on* the object you want it to refer to.

Functions which don't have an explicit scope from which they are called, default to global context, though the function itself isn't global and can leverage all the variables in its parent context due to a closure.